# How to save and use value of cookie in Gatling?

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I am relatively new to using Gatling for load testing and all aspects are still not quite clear. The testing scenario involves capturing a cookie value, which can be: 2, 4, 6. I used the following:

```
http("User generation")
.get("url")
.check(headerRegex("Set-Cookie", """status_id=(.*?);""").saveAs("status"))
```

The result is an error :

```
headerRegex((Set-Cookie, status_id=(.*?);)).find.exists, found nothing
```

I did everything according to the documentation, but the result is not achieved, tell me how can I pull the value of the cookie and use this value in the future scripts? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `getCookieValue`, see [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_helpers/#getting-a-cookie-value).